# Binary file that can only be printed in hex format , but not binary format

Tags: c, binary

[Here](https://github.com/IthacaCow/C14-Parser/blob/master/controlSignal3.bin) is a binary file that contains:

`0xff 0xff 0xff`

which is exactly three bytes.

I try to use the `dump_file` function [here](https://github.com/IthacaCow/C14-Parser/blob/master/debug.c)

```
#include "table.h"
#include "debug.h"

typedef unsigned int Code


void dump_file( char* fileName[] )
{
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        log_info("File: %s",fileName[i]);
        FILE* file = fopen(fileName[i],"rb");
        fread(&c,sizeof(char),1,file);
        while( !feof(file) ){
            dump_code( c , 8 );
            fread(&c,sizeof(char),1,file);
        }
    }
}

void dump_code( Code code,int BitsNum )
{
    int mask = 1 << (BitsNum-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < BitsNum ; ++i)
    {
        if(i%8==0)putchar('|');
        putchar((mask & code) ? '1' : '0');
        code <<= 1;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

to print the file in binary format, but it prints nothing.  ( Somehow it bumps into `EOF` in an undesirable manner ?? )

I also use the Unix unity `xxd`.
When I signal `xxd` to print my file in binary, it prints nothing.  But if I choose to print hexademically, it prints as expected.  What's wrong with this file?

This file is generated by [a parser](https://github.com/IthacaCow/C14-Parser).  The C program uses `fseek` to jump to various location in a file and print the corresponding binary code.  It might go like:

> 0th byte --> 1st byte --> 3rd byte --> 5th byte --> 2nd byte --> 4th byte --> 6th byte

It is guaranteed that there is no "leak" in the resulting file, i.e, every byte will be traversed.

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

---

### Update 1

While pointed out by samgak that this might be due to the interpretation of `0xff`, some of my other experiments indicate that even file containing:

0x01 0x01 0x01

which results in the same phenomenon.

---

### Update 2

Here's the relevent code that write `Code` into file:

```
#define CODE_FILE_NUM 3
void writeCode( FILE* out[] , Code code ){
    for (int i = 0; i < CODE_FILE_NUM; ++i){
        fwrite(&code,sizeof(char),1,out[i]);    
        code >>= 8; 
    }
}
```

`Code` is an `unsigned int`, which has 4 bytes.  Function `writeCode` will only consider the lower 3 bytes and write each byte into 3 seperate files.

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Not in an off site link.

Comment: Please post some self-contained code here so we can try to reproduce your problem. But in the mean time, what is the `Code` type in ` dump_code( Code code,int BitsNum )`?

Comment: FWIW, there's nothing wrong with adding offsite links to questions (or answers) on Stack Exchange but you **must** post the relevant material locally as well so that your post will make sense in case your links become invalid.  Remember, questions aren't just to solve your current problem, they should also be a resource for people in the future.

Comment: Even your posted code doesn't contain all info critical to how your functions will run. Ex: What is `Code` ? Post a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can be cut and pasted into a compilable source file and executed to reproduce the issue you're describing.

Comment: Perhaps, it has failed to open the file. (this displayed something if you have been success.) One reason is not to close the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason.
It's because I forgot to close the output files.

I tried to dump **unclosed** binary files ( That is: **open and read data from files that haven't been closed.** ) , which resulted in unpredictable behaviors.